# Why I'm not able to load mkl module that I've installed using pip?

Tags: python

I would like to install MKL module, and I do it using `pip install MKL` , it prints out that mkl installed successfully, but once I want to load/import it from python, I’ve get this error:

```
>>> import mkl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mkl
```

Any idea what would be the problem?

Comment: probably you are using python2 and installing using pip3 or viceversa. Check the output of "pip --version " and make sure it is the correct version.

Comment: I've checked it, I'm using pip2. Now looks weird for me

Comment: does this only happen with MKL or any other libraries too?

Comment: it happens only with MKL

Answer (score 1):

At least for Anaconda python, this can be fixed by installing the package `conda install mkl-service`, which allows you to call `import mkl`.

On the other hand, it is not available via `pip install`, so I cannot say how it would work there.

Comment: Using python 3.8, I was able to `pip install mkl-service`. Solved the issue for me (though it created another one).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use anaconda. It has default mkl package in it.